# Update multiple docs with different values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Don't think this is at all possible but wanted to check.

If I have the following documents:

```
doc1 : {
  _id: 1,
  name: 'John Smith',
  age: 20
}

doc2 : {
  _id: 2,
  name: 'Jane Smith',
  age: 22
}
```

I want the client to be able to pass me both docs in the same request for update.  In this case maybe add an address to both docs.

Is there a way the I can send one update statement to mongo such that it updates both of the documents with the name values?

I.E. from client:

```
doc1 : {
  _id: 1,
  name: 'John Smith',
  age: 20,
  address: '123 Street'
}

doc2 : {
  _id: 2,
  name: 'Jane Smith',
  age: 22,
  address: '456 Way'
}
```

Currently I am iterating over the values and updating one at a time.  Problem with that is mongoose/mongodb updates are async, so I cannot reliably tell the client that I updated each result until all update callbacks have fired.  I have a counter to make sure I receive N number of callbacks then I send a response.

Comment: Splitting it into two updates is required.  Take a look at the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library for ways to improve on the callback counter approach.

Comment: If you were applying the *same* update to multiple documents, you could use the `multi:true` flag for [`update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#update-multiple-documents).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the updates I do are one at a time, but what's nice for me is that they are synchronous. =)

It seems you can bulk load though with the mongoimport tool:  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport--upsertFields.  You can do bulk upserts that way.

Otherwise I don't believe you can do it in one command via a client.